# CodeIgniter reference return object inside model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a model in code igniter which gets a photo object as a row

return $query->row();

I need to get the photoid from this object and use it in another function inside the same model.

Please suggest what should i do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the photo ID to a variable;

```
$photo_id = $query->row('photo_id');
```

You can then us it like this;

```
$this->method($photo_id);
```

If you want the photo_id to be replaced by whatever that function does, you could do this;

```
$query->row('photo_id') = $this->method($query->row('photo_id'));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Call the model function in constructor and put in array like below:

```
class Demo extends CI_Controller {
var $data = array();
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('photo');
    $this->data = $this->photo->getData();

}
function index()
{
    print_r($this->data);
}
function user()
{
    print_r($this->data);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i've correctly understood :

Model :

```
public function myfunction()
{
    //stuff

    $photo = $this->mysecondfunction();
    $photo_id = $photo->id;

    //stuff

}

private function mysecondfunction()
{
    //stuff

    return $query->row();
}
```

**OR**

---

Controller :

```
$photo = $this->my_model->getPhoto();
$this->my_model->doStuffWithMyPhotoId($photo->id);
```

Model :

```
public function getPhoto()
{
    //stuff

    return $query->row();
}


public function doStuffWithMyPhotoId($photoid)
{
    //stuff
}
```